# What to do when I can't find sheep?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently playing Minecraft 1.1 and I can't find any sheep! I know that there are sheep in this world because I have seen the same world in videos with sheep. Does anyone have any tips or ideas on what I should do? I simply **can't** find any sheep at all!

Comment: That's very common problem. How much time have you spent looking for them? Once it took me almost two full Minecraft-days.

Comment: The newest version is 1.1, FYI.

Answer (score 21):

If you can't find sheep for wool (I'm assuming) you can always kill spiders and craft their string into wool.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/String

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is to simply go for a walk and look for them. Bring a sword, food and wheat. I tend to find sheep in open stretches of a "plains" biome devoid of trees. I've also had decent success finding them on the side of hills, again, devoid of trees. They tend to flock in groups of 6 or so.

If you find any sheep simply hold the wheat in your hand and they will follow you around. Use this to corral them into a pen/holding area for future use or to find them again.

Another option is to load up a program like MCEdit and look around the world for entities (small red blocks), select them, analyze (to ensure you have sheep or not other mobs or dropped items), then copy and paste. Not quite as easy as it sounds but can sometimes help.

Comment: You may also want to bring shears, if you're wanting to harvest the wool right away.  And a stack of logs and torches in case it is very late and you need to set up a camp.  Sometimes it can take a very long time to find specific animals.

Answer (score 4):

You can encourage passive mobs like Sheep to spawn by creating a large, flat grassy area. They only spawn on grass blocks, so having a big, open, flat grass field gives you more chances.

Relevant wiki pages:

[Sheep](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep)

[Grass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grass)

Comment: Animals don't spawn anymore, they're created with the chunks as you walk into them and continue existing until they die... only way to get more animals is to breed the ones you find (or keep exploring)

Comment: Wow, OK. I haven't messed with animals much since 1.0, my bad. Damn wiki needs updated.

Comment: There is a *small* chance for them to spawn, as far as I am aware. I think someone needs to do some code delving.

Comment: @Pureferret From experience, they definitely do still spawn *very* rarely. On a floating island it's possible to get new animals eventually, if there's grass.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I seem to recall reading that animals will spawn if there are less than 11 in the current chunk (overall, not by species) and other conditions like grass and light are met).

Comment: @Robotnik Yep, something like that. But the timer for the check is quite slow, and when it ticks it picks the chunk to check randomly from the loaded chunks, so it can take many days before a particular chunk gets a new animal pack spawned.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I first started playing - couldn't figure out how to make bread so just killed everything nearby and ate it. Didn't realise they wouldn't respawn.

Ended up just heading into the next chunk, building a large enclosed area and luring that chunk's sheep into it. Once there it was easy to breed them.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go to another chunk, and just keep running around with wheat until sheep, pigs, cows, chickens, etc start to follow but if you're scared to get lost, put lamps down where your trail is, and we getting animals to follow you, you have to keep turning around and making sure they are still following or make sure they see the wool, it's better to just walk backwards watching them the entire way.

Answer (score -3):

You could move into a village if you find one. Make sure there is a black smith house with some good stuff. Villages are usually located near sheep.

Comment: -1: Sheep are spawned randomly and have no connection to villages.

Comment: The only correlation I can think of is that both Sheep and Villages spawn in the plains biome. That said, you're still more likely to come across sheep before coming across a village